# Permission Issues with Wordpress Multisite running on AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, permissions, bitnami, multisite

I am sure there are many things not done yet to eliminate the technical frustrations that i am currently experiencing with Bitnami Wordpress Multisite 4.6-1 running on AWS. I am taking this opportunity to highlight the issue i am facing on stackoverflow community to get some help, learn, grow and most importantly be able to help as well. This is my first Question here and i am afraid that i am unable to post more 2 links here because i am not allowed to.

To Begin with, There seem to be Permissions Issues on Wordpress Multisite running on Aws EC2 which was setup and configured through Bitnami. Sadly documentation and Articles on Bitnami Wiki are not updated for the latest version of Wordpress Multisite and i am not comfortable using Bitnami Osx Application to manage Wordpress because i am not using Bitnami Cloud Hosting but AWS Ec2.

**AWS EC2 Configuration Details:**

**Instance Type:** T2 Micro

**Elastic IP:** Yes

**Security Groups:** Grants access to Bitnami WordPress

**IAM User**: 2 Users, Enabled with Following Policy. 
 1. AdministratorAccess
 2. AmazonEC2ContainerServiceFullAccess
 3. AmazonVPCFullAccess

**Wordpress Network:** Able to Install Themes &  Plugins on Network and Problems are listed below. 
**Wordpress Site Running on Network:**  Able to Activate Network Plugins/ Themes. Able Import xml data on Site with minor issues as the Theme Installed on the network is Outdated.

**Terminal:** Able to establish SSH connection using pem key. browse, create files and delete any newly created files using bash commands however issue is with deleting unwanted Plugins / Theme by removing using same commands even through i did run chmod 777 multiple times to ensure read, write and execute is enabled but there is no Success.

**Wordpress Issues:**

1. Unable to Update Plugins through Dashboard weather Paid/Unpaid. Please check the screenshots. 
   [Plugin Update - Failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIGNG.png)
2. Unable to Uninstall any outdated theme weather Active / Inactive on Sites. - Failed][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcOL9.png)

**Troubleshooting Steps 1:**

**Network Setup** - Implemented through Terminal using VIM command  :

**1** - Added the following to wp-config.php file in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/ above the line reading /* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging.

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1); */:
```

]

**2**- Added the following to .htaccess file in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/, replacing other WordPress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**Result:** NO Success.

**Troubleshooting Steps 2:**

SSH Connection to Instance : Succes
Create New Files: Yes
Delete Newly Files: Yes (using `rm filename`)
Delete Empty Dir: Yes (Using `rmdir`)
Delete Outdated Theme Dir: Permission Denied (rm: cannot remove 'startit': Is a directory)

**Note:** I did run CHMOD 777 at the beginning of SSH session again.

**Result :** NO Success.

Troubleshooting Step 3

**FTP FileZilla:** Connected through filezilla using PEM key.

1. Able to Upload new folders and files.
2. Unable to delete unwanted folders ;
   Error: Permission Denied.

**Result :** NO Success.

Please know that i very new to all that i mentioned above and i am sure there are many troubleshooting steps that i have to follow. Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used a cloud server with BITNAMI, and just hated it. Not for me. Its a bare system. No cpanel, WHM, or anything exciting. Just an empty linux OS. We had spent a week getting it up. Finally decided to can it.

use command line:
What we did to fix the permission issues is CMD into your server as ROOT!

make sure you are root, if you are not root make sure you SUDO -SU. 
File folders have to be "0755"
Files have to be "0644"
setting all files, and folders correctly made a world of difference.